# Why isn't SparseArray working in this case?

Tags: replacement, list-manipulation, sparse-arrays

This works:

```
SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2}]\
(* {{1, 0}, {0, 2}} *)
```

This works:

```
SparseArray[{{1, 1}, {1, 2}} -> 1]
(* {{1, 1}} *)
```

But it seems a combination of this kind of syntax for rules does not, or at least not as I expect it to:

```
SparseArray[{{{1, 1}, {1, 2}} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2}]
(* {{0, 0}, {0, 2}} *)
```

I expected to get

```
(* {{1, 1}, {0, 2}} *)
```

which I could obtain by splitting up the positions to be assigned to `1` using

```
SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 1, {1, 2} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2}]
(* {{1, 1}, {0, 2}} *)
```

but this gets unwieldy if I want to accomplish this for many more points.

Is there something I'm misunderstanding about `SparseArray`? As near as I can tell, there's nothing in the documentation that explains what's going on here.

**Edit**: Adding some details about what I plan on doing with this. I'm building an 18x18 array where the entry in the $i$th row and $j$th column represents the "effectiveness" $a_{i,j}$ of a factor $i$ on another factor $j$. Effectiveness is defined by
$$a_{i,j}=\begin{cases}2&\text{if very effective}\\1&\text{if neutrally effective}\\\frac{1}{2}&\text{if not very effective}\\0&\text{if completely ineffective}\end{cases}$$
Once created, I was planning on generating a sort of "weighted" graph with this array as the adjacency matrix where the value of $a_{i,j}$ determines the style (say, color or thickness or opacity) of the edge connecting node $i$ to node $j$; essentially a visual representation of the effect $i$ has on $j$. This process is outside the immediate scope of the current question and something I'd like to look into on my own until I run into trouble.

For a concrete example, I'll construct the first row of the array using [ciao](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/ciao)'s suggestion with `Alternatives`. The $i=1$ factor has effectiveness
$$a_{1,j}=\begin{cases}2&\text{if }j\in\{2,10,15\}\\1&\text{if }j\in\{1,3,4,11,12,13,16,18\}\\\frac{1}{2}&\text{if }j\in\{5,6,7,8,9,14,17\}\\0&\text{never}\end{cases}$$
Denoting the effectiveness intensities by

```
very = {2, 10, 15};
neutral = {1, (*...*), 18};
not = {5, (*...*), 17};
```

I can generate the first row with

```
SparseArray[
    {
     {1, Alternatives@@very} -> 2,
     {1, Alternatives@@neutral} -> 1,
     {1, Alternatives@@not} -> 1/2
    }, {1, 18}
 ]
```

letting `SparseArray` handle the case where $i$ doesn't affect $j$ at all. I was getting an error message about the dimension being undetermined, so I tacked on the `{1, 18}` at the end to make sure I get an appropriately sized array.

Comment: Workaround: `SparseArray[{Thread[{{1, 1}, {1, 2}} -> 1], {2, 2} -> 2} // Flatten]`

Comment: @J.M. Neat, that will definitely come in handy.

Comment: `Alternatives` is your friend here...

Comment: Ah, ciao's is much more compact: `SparseArray[{{1, 2} | {1, 1} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2}]`

Comment: @J.M.`SparseArray[{{1, 1 | 2} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2}]`

Comment: @user170231: As far as your question, yes to "Is there something I'm misunderstanding ...": in the form in use here, the rules are expected to be a list of position/value pairs *or* a list of positions with a rule to 1 value or a list of values of the same length as positions. If you want to nest them as in your non-working example, the right of the rule must be a list, e.g. `SparseArray[{{{1, 1}, {1, 2}} -> {1, 1}, {2, 2} -> 2}]` - personally, I find patterns/alternatives more transparent. It would be nice if you could expand on "...many more points" with a clear example of your problem.

Comment: @ciao Thanks for taking the time to point that out. I've added some more details about my problem. Your suggestion with `Alternatives` was very helpful!

Comment: Probably more useful: how about generating a smaller matrix example where all the $a_{i,j}$ were specified? Also: did you know `Graph[]` supports `EdgeWeight`? You could consider generating the graph directly and generate the weighted adjacency matrix as a side result.

Comment: @J.M. I'm sure I've seen it before but never used it myself. It could definitely work if I can figure out a way to set up all the edge connections properly.

Comment: @ciao Haven't tested this, but there is a theoretical risk that using a pattern on the LHS of the rule will cause Mathematica to try to match all possible index pairs one by one ... which should be slow.

Comment: `Flatten@{{1, #} -> 2 & /@ very, {1, #} -> 1 & /@ neutral, {1, #} -> 0 & /@ not}` ?

Comment: @Szabolcs: Of course, trade-off as always, clarity vs speed. Depends on size/structure of actual problem, which I see OP has filled in, and your comment solution is a nice, concise way...

Comment: Note that you don't need to do the individual alternatives, just use e.g., `Alternatives@@very`, etc...